# User doesn't have permission to delete a case

Tags: sharing, permission-sets, servicecloud, case-object, crud

I have two permission sets:

**firstOne**: contains only "Manage Cases" permission and Modify All on Cases

**secondOne**: contains all the first one but also has a lot of other settings related or not to Cases object

With firstOne permission set user tries to delete a case it doesn't own but there is an error: You do not have permission to delete this case

With secondOne permission set user successfully deletes any other's cases.

I can not understand which more properties I sould add to firstOne permission set to allow user to delete cases.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to delete records in Salesforce is controlled by the role hierarchy. Setting a sharing model to ""Public Read/Write"" alone does not give users the right to delete others records. There are 2 scenarios in which a user can delete a record:

1. The user attempting to delete the record is a System Administrator.
2. The user attempting to delete the record is the owner, or higher on the role hierarchy than the record owner.

Any other user that attempts to delete a record will receive an "Insufficient Privilege" error message.

Those below you on the role hierarchy may have read/write privileges according to the sharing model rules, however, they may not delete information from those individuals above them in that hierarchy.

Comment: N.B. #1 is really permission `Modify All Data` which happens to come for free with System Administrator profile but can be granted to other profiles or permission sets; [see Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327316&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

Permission modify all ignore all sharing rules/other FLS permission. It basically set the user as admin (for the Case object in your settings), therefore it should work also with the first permission set.

In Salesforce when the user tried to delete record without permission he usually get an error of 'insufficient access....', the message you are getting 'You do not have permission to delete this case' seem customization.
Check if you have any trigger that run validation on case deletion.

Comment: It was my suggestion as well, but no labels for this text etc, no mentions of secondOne permission set in the code as well